# Change document root folder of Apache web server on Linux

Tags: linux, apache, document-root

My PC is windows 8.1 and Linux mint 16 dual boot pc.I created Local web server on Linux Mint.It's document root is "/var/www".But all my projects are located on a NTFS partion which i mount to linux and use(/media/randika/HardDisk/Works/Lab).I need to make a symbolic link to projects folder or change document root of Apache server.How can i do it?`

My 000-default.conf file located in sites-available folder

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.when mounting a partition, linux automatically sets permissions for all files and directories in that partition.Permissions cannot change after mounted.Therefore Unmounted the partition,changed umask value to 022 in etc/fstab and created a symbolic link.Everything works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Just change inside your Virtualhost

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

to

```
DocumentRoot /media/randika/HardDisk/Works/Lab
```

and add the rights on the new directory

```
<Directory "/media/randika/HardDisk/Works/Lab">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
```

And restart Apache for reload the configuration

Comment: Thanks @Bugs..but it gives 403 forbidden error."You dont have permission to access / on this server."